# Video Broadcast from mobile phone camera to a desktop application

Tags: c#, mobile, bluetooth

I want to develop a Windows application in .Net which will consume a video stream broadcasted over Bluetooth from a mobile phone camera. The video stream will be displayed in a PictureBox and the user will be able to take image snapshoots. How could I develop this in C#? Is it technically feasible? Can you give me some starting points (docs, links, code-samples) to start with?

Comment: First you should check if your phone supports VDP - Video Distribution Profile of Bluetooth. Second you should check your Windows target OS if it supports VDP and if not you'll have to implement it by yourself and here you deal only with C/C++ programming.